# How refresh image using javascript

Tags: jsf-2, primefaces

Using primefaces fileupload i am trying to show recently uploaded image in img tag just above the upload compontent but it shows only after i manually press F5 or hit enter on browser i have tried location.reload() and histry.go(0) but image is not loading

```
<img  height="100"     src="relativepath/productId"/>
<p:fileUpload oncomplete="history.go(0)"   fileUploadListener="#{productController.upload}" mode="advanced"    
dragDropSupport="false" allowTypes="/(\.|\/)(gif|jpe?g|png)$/" />
```

Comment: you'd need to have the uploader change the img's `src` after the upload completes and you get the 'official' URL for that newly uploaded image.

Comment: the upload method in controller does that job and it will upload the image at relative path with name productId but i need to refresh why?

Comment: `history.go(0)` won't necessarily do another http request to see if anything changed. it can freely used cached data, which means whatever image was loaded originally, not whatever you've just uploaded.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

do not limit yourself to javascript. an update after ajax, with a timestamp parameter in url will work fine.

this should be the xhtml code:

```
<h:panelGroup id="panelToUpdate">
    <img height="100" src="relativepath/productId?t=#{myManagedBean.currentTimeInMillis}"/>
</h:panelGroup>
<p:fileUpload update="panelToUpdate" fileUploadListener="#{productController.upload}" 
    mode="advanced" dragDropSupport="false" allowTypes="/(\.|\/)(gif|jpe?g|png)$/" />
```

and this should be the method in your managed bean:

```
public long getCurrentTimeInMillis()
{
    return System.currentTimeMillis();
}
```

Answer (score -1):

The following code loads the image every 1 second... Hope I helped

```
<div id="wraper">
</div>
<style>
    var t=setInterval(runFunction,1000);
    function runFunction() {
        document.getElementById("p1").innerHTML = '<img  height="100"     src="relativepath/productId"/>
        <p:fileUpload oncomplete="history.go(0)"   fileUploadListener="#{productController.upload}" mode="advanced"    
        dragDropSupport="false" allowTypes="/(\.|\/)(gif|jpe?g|png)$/" />'
    }
</style>
```

Comment: this should not work. `p:fileUpload` is a component that is converted to native html and javascript on the server side. you cannot expect it to be rendered after being placed by a javascript function.